# Webpack bundling causes Unknown provider $injector/unpr error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refactoring, restangular

### Unknown provider - NavigationCtrl, Restangular

I'm currently working through my old projects to get them fully working again as a small refactoring exercise and I came across some AngularJS code that doesn't compile anymore. I believe this is down to the updated dependencies as I have not changed the functionality of this source code for at least 3 years.

The issue I'm getting is:

> angular.js:15567 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AProvider <- A <- NavigationCtrl
>   https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$injector/unpr?p0=AProvider%20%3C-%20A%20%3C-%20NavigationCtrl
>
> ```
> at angular.js:138
> at angular.js:4924
> at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:5084)
> at angular.js:4929
> at getService (angular.js:5084)
> at injectionArgs (angular.js:5109)
> at Object.invoke (angular.js:5133)
> at $controllerInit (angular.js:11704)
> at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:10517)
> at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9832)
> ```

I understand this as an injection issue. I'm trying to inject something that Angular doesn't know about. It's a little confusing as I've not worked with AngularJS for a while now (having used Angular 2+).

My `app.js` file looks like this:

```
angular.module('qaDashboard', ['restangular'])
    .run(['$anchorScroll', function ($anchorScroll) {
        $anchorScroll.yOffset = 85;   // always scroll by 50 extra pixels
    }]);

angular.module('qaDashboard').controller('NavigationCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    $scope.scrollTo = function (id) {
        $location.hash(id);
        $anchorScroll();
    };
});

// Environment
require('../components/environments/script.js');
require('../components/environments/style.scss');

// Feature
require('../components/features/script.js');
require('../components/features/style.scss');

// Day
require('../components/days/script.js');
require('../components/days/style.scss');

// Hour
require('../components/hours/script.js');

// Report Data (URL & JSON)
require('../components/report/script.js');
require('../components/report/style.scss');

// Index Style
require('../stylesheets/style.scss');
```

And my `index.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="qaDashboard">

<head>
    <title>DASHBOARD</title>
    <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/restangular/src/restangular.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/app.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <p>Regression Test Dashboard</p>
        <div ng-controller="NavigationCtrl" class="navbarAlign">
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Dev')" class="btn">Dev</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('QA')" class="btn">QA</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Staging')" class="btn">Staging</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Staging_EMEA')" class="btn">Staging EMEA</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Production')" class="btn">Production</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Production_EMEA')" class="btn">Production EMEA</a>
            <!--<a class="btn">[Do stuff]</a>-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <environments>

    </environments>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried removing individual controllers and that hasn't worked. Am I missing something obvious here? Has the syntax/ API changed a lot since I last worked with this code?

**The `app,js` file gets bundled by webpack** - dunno if that's the root of the issue. I know for a fact that this code worked perfectly fine before. I just feel like I'm missing something trivial and it's proving a little difficult to spot.

My `package.json` - if it helps:

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.5.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.7.8",
    "body-parser": "~1.19.0",
    "concat-map": "0.0.1",
    "convert-time": "^0.3.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "debug": "~4.1.1",
    "express": "~4.17.1",
    "jenkins-api": "^0.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "restangular": "^1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "acorn": "^6.2.0",
    "acorn-dynamic-import": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "promise": "^8.0.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "url-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.36.1"
  }
}
```

EDIT:

I've tried this:

```
angular.module('qaDashboard', ['restangular'])
    .controller('NavigationCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
        $scope.scrollTo = function (id) {
            $location.hash(id);
            $anchorScroll();
        }
            .run(['$anchorScroll', function ($anchorScroll) {
                $anchorScroll.yOffset = 85;   // always scroll by 50 extra pixels
            }])
    });
```

without luck.

Edit 2:

I just tried georgeawg's response with the following code:

```
angular.module('qaDashboard', ['restangular'])
    .controller('NavigationCtrl', ["$scope", "$location", "$anchorScroll",
        function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
            $scope.scrollTo = function (id) {
                $location.hash(id);
                $anchorScroll();
            }
        }]);

// Environment
require('../components/environments/script.js');
require('../components/environments/style.scss');

// Feature
require('../components/features/script.js');
require('../components/features/style.scss');

// Day
require('../components/days/script.js');
require('../components/days/style.scss');

// Hour
require('../components/hours/script.js');

// Report Data (URL & JSON)
require('../components/report/script.js');
require('../components/report/style.scss');

// Index Style
require('../stylesheets/style.scss');
```

I'm getting an `angular.js:15567 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AProvider <- A` issue now.

My components look like this:

```
angular.module('qaDashboard').component('environments', {
    controller: function (Restangular) {
        this.$onInit = () => {
            Restangular.one('environments').get().then((response) => {
                this.environments = response.environments;
            });
        }
    },
    template: require('./template.html'),

}).filter('formattedEnvironment', () => {
    return (item) => {
        return item.replace('-', ' ')
                   .replace('_', ' ')
                   .replace('_', ' ')
                   .replace('_', ' ');
    }
});
```

```
<div id="{{environment}}" ng-repeat="environment in $ctrl.environments" class="borderedHolder">
    <h1>{{environment | formattedEnvironment}}</h1>
    <features environment='environment' >

    </features>
</div>
```

(there are several components and they all use `Restangular` like above ^

Edit 3: I've tried:

with: `angular.js:15567 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'EnvironmentsController' is not registered.`

```
angular.module('qaDashboard').component('environments', {
    controller: 'EnvironmentsController', ['Restangular', function (Restangular) {
        this.$onInit = () => {
            Restangular.one('environments').get().then((response) => {
                this.environments = response.environments;
            });
        }
    },
        template]: require('./template.html'),

})
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your controller definition up, before you make the call to `.run`

Comment: Still the same issue. - please see edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Inline Array Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation):

```
angular.module('qaDashboard', ['restangular'])
.controller('NavigationCtrl', ["$scope","$location","$anchorScroll",
  function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    $scope.scrollTo = function (id) {
        $location.hash(id);
        $anchorScroll();
    }
}]);
```

---

## Update

To help you find this kind of problem before you uglify, use Strict Dependency Injection.

From the Docs:

> ## Using Strict Dependency Injection
>
> You can add an `ng-strict-di` directive on the same element as `ng-app` to opt into strict DI mode:
>
> ```
> <!doctype html>
> <html ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
> <body>
>   I can add: {{ 1 + 2 }}.
>   <script src="angular.js"></script>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> Strict mode throws an error whenever a service tries to use implicit annotations.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Strict Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-strict-dependency-injection)
- [AngularJS ng-app Directive API Reference - with ng-strict-di](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/docs/api/ng/directive/ngApp#with-ngstrictdi-)

---

## Update #2

Use [Inline Array Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation):

> Please can you show me based on my edit 3?

```
app.component('environments', {
    ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶:̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶R̶e̶s̶t̶a̶n̶g̶u̶l̶a̶r̶)̶ ̶{̶
    controller: ["Restangular", function(Restangular) {
        this.$onInit = () => {
            Restangular.one('environments').get().then((response) => {
                this.environments = response.environments;
            });
        }
    ̶}̶,̶
    }],
    template: require('./template.html'),    
})
```

From the Docs:

> ## Implicit Annotation
>
> > **Careful:** If you plan to [minify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) your code, your service names will get renamed and break your app.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Implicit Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just tried this and I think now my issue is with my components? Please see edit 2

Comment: It appears to be an issue with Restangular - I think?

Comment: Okay that's great, I've solved that issue. Just getting `Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'NavigationCtrl' is not registered.`. Any ideas?

Comment: This answer solves problems with minification causing [$injector:undef](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/undef) errors. [$controller:ctrlreg](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$controller/ctrlreg) errors are another issue which should be asked in a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Many thanks, much appreciated. I created another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135511/the-controller-with-the-name-xxx-is-not-registered-refactoring-old-project-tha

Comment: thanks! skipping minification/optimization did the trick for me.