# The controller with the name XXX is not registered - refactoring old project that uses webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, refactoring

I'm currently refactoring one of my old AngularJS projects which worked before, but since updating the dependencies, has stopped working.

I'm getting an error in the console that says:

> The controller with the name 'NavigationCtrl' is not registered.

My `app.js` file looks like the following:

```
angular.module('qaDashboard', ['restangular'])
    .controller('NavigationCtrl', ["$scope", "$location", "$anchorScroll",
        function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
            $scope.scrollTo = function (id) {
                $location.hash(id);
                $anchorScroll();
            }
        }]);

// Environment
require('../components/environments/script.js');
require('../components/environments/style.scss');

// Feature
require('../components/features/script.js');
require('../components/features/style.scss');

// Day
require('../components/days/script.js');
require('../components/days/style.scss');

// Hour
require('../components/hours/script.js');

// Report Data (URL & JSON)
require('../components/report/script.js');
require('../components/report/style.scss');

// Index Style
require('../stylesheets/style.scss');
```

and my `index.html` file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="qaDashboard">

<head>
    <title>DASHBOARD</title>
    <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/restangular/src/restangular.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/app.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <p>Regression Test Dashboard</p>
        <div ng-controller="NavigationCtrl" class="navbarAlign">
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Dev')" class="btn">Dev</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('QA')" class="btn">QA</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Staging')" class="btn">Staging</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Staging_EMEA')" class="btn">Staging EMEA</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Production')" class="btn">Production</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Production_EMEA')" class="btn">Production EMEA</a>
            <!--<a class="btn">[Do stuff]</a>-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <environments>

    </environments>
</body>

</html>
```

This `app.js` file gets bundled via Webpack (as you can see) - I don't know if the problem is with that?

At first I assumed it was a typo but that's not the case.

How can I register my component?

I've not had to do this before as I mentioned earlier, my project worked fine before updating the dependencies.

### EDIT:

I have implemented your suggestion but it now gives me:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AProvider <- A

### My app.js:

```
angular.module('qaDashboard', ['restangular'])
    .controller('NavigationCtrl', ["$scope", "$location", "$anchorScroll",
        function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
            $scope.scrollTo = function (id) {
                $location.hash(id);
                $anchorScroll();
            }
        }]);

// Environment
require('../components/environments/script.js');
require('../components/environments/style.scss');

// // Feature
// require('../components/features/script.js');
// require('../components/features/style.scss');

// // Day
// require('../components/days/script.js');
// require('../components/days/style.scss');

// // Hour
// require('../components/hours/script.js');

// // Report Data (URL & JSON)
// require('../components/report/script.js');
// require('../components/report/style.scss');

// // Index Style
// require('../stylesheets/style.scss');
```

and `../components/environments/script.js`:

```
angular.module('qaDashboard')
    .component('environments', {
        controller: function (Restangular) {
            this.$onInit = () => {
                Restangular.one('environments').get().then((response) => {
                    this.environments = response.environments;
                });
            }
        },
        template: require('./template.html'),
    }).filter('formattedEnvironment', () => {
        return (item) => {
            return item.replace('-', ' ')
                .replace('_', ' ')
                .replace('_', ' ')
                .replace('_', ' ');
        }
    });
```

### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="qaDashboard">

<head>
    <title>DASHBOARD</title>
    <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/restangular/src/restangular.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/app.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <p>Regression Test Dashboard</p>
        <div ng-controller="NavigationCtrl" class="navbarAlign">
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Dev')" class="btn">Dev</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('QA')" class="btn">QA</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Staging')" class="btn">Staging</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Staging_EMEA')" class="btn">Staging EMEA</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Production')" class="btn">Production</a>
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('Production_EMEA')" class="btn">Production EMEA</a>
            <!--<a class="btn">[Do stuff]</a>-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <environments>

    </environments>
</body>

</html>
```

And template:

```
<div id="{{environment}}" ng-repeat="environment in $ctrl.environments" class="borderedHolder">
    <h1>{{environment | formattedEnvironment}}</h1>
    <!-- <features environment='environment'>

    </features> -->
</div>
```

Comment: It probably got unregistered when another component was added. Only the first module declaration should have dependencies specified.

Comment: @georgeawg I'm unsure what this means exactly. Does this suggest I need to change where my component is declared?

Comment: See [**Update #2**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57120120/5535245) in [Webpack bundling causes Unknown provider $injector/unpr error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118069/webpack-bundling-causes-unknown-provider-injector-unpr-error).

Comment: @georgeawg Worked. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first module declaration should have dependencies specified.

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> angular.module('qaDashboard', ['restangular'])
> .controller('NavigationCtrl',NavigationCtrl) 
>
> angular.module('qaDashboard', ['restangular'])
> .component('environments', {/* ... */})
> ```

Declaring dependencies again will cause the controller to be unregistered.

### Correct

```
 angular.module('qaDashboard', ['restangular'])
.controller('NavigationCtrl',NavigationCtrl) 

 angular.module('qaDashboard')
.component('environments', {/* .. */})
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Module Creation vs Retrieval](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval)
- [AngularJS angular.module API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)

Comment: Hi, I'm still getting an issue with an unknown provider like with my previous question you helped answer yesterday :/ Please see my edit